# Python create/import custom module in same directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple python script and import a couple of custom classes.  I'd like to do this as one module.  Here is what I have:

point/point.py

```
class Point:
   """etc."""
```

point/pointlist.py

```
class PointList:
   """etc."""
```

point/__init__.py

```
from . import point, pointlist
```

script.py

```
import sys, point
verbose = False
pointlist = PointList()
```

When I run `script.py`  I get `NameError: name 'PointList' is not defined`

What's weird is that in point/, all three of the module files (__init__, pointlist, point) have a `.pyc` version created that was not there before, so it seems like it is finding the files.  The class files themselves also compile without any errors.

I feel like I'm probably missing something very simple, so please bear with me.

Comment: Python is case-sensitive - is this a typo in your question, or the actual error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, I seem to have made a blunder in my earlier answer and comments:

The problem here is that you should access the objects in `point` through the module you import:

`point/__init__.py`:

```
from point import Point
from pointlist import PointList
```

`script.py:`

```
import sys, point
verbose = False
pointlist = point.PointList()
```

You access `PointList` through the import `point` which imports whatever is in `__init__.py`

If you want to access `PointList` and `Point` directly you could use `from point import Point, PointList` in `script.py` or the least preferable `from point import *`

Again, sorry for my earlier error.

Comment: I tried renaming `point` (directory) to `points` and changing the script code to `import sys, points` and it has exactly the same effect (still creates .pyc files for all three files in points/)

Comment: When I change it to `from . import point, pointlist.PointList` I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I revised my answer, I was off before.

Comment: Works!  Thank you.  Is there any way to add Point and PointList to the global namespace so I don't have to say `point.PointList`, etc. every time?

Comment: yes, just use `from point import Point, PointList` in `script.py`